# como sacar el iva con varios porcentajes

Tags: c#

**

Este es mi código lo que sucede es que quiero sacar el iva de un producto.

Ejemplo: cerveza 3000, con el iva seria 3600, pero para ello esta condicionado: lo primero que de 0 a 4000 tenga un descuento del 20% y de 4001 a 10000 de un 50%, también debo hacerlo con la tasa bomberil que de 3501 a 10000 sea del 2% así:

| Impuesto | Desde | Hasta | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IVA | 0 | 4000 | 20% |
|  | 4001 | 10000 | 50% |
| Tasa bomberil | 0 | 3500 | 0% |
|  | 3501 | 10000 | 2% |

El valor por retornar debe ser de `3000 + (3000*0,20)+(3000*0)= 3600`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace BackendPorcentaje
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static object conver;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double prod1, prod2, prod3, ivaprod1, ivaprod2, ivaprod3, total;
            string linea;
            string usuario;
            string a;
            string b;
            string c;
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese su nombre");
            usuario = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"El resultado de la conversion es: {conver}");
            Console.WriteLine($"El valor de usuario es: {usuario}");
            // un metodo que se llama tryparse
            Console.WriteLine($"Bienvenido al sistema {usuario}");
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el primer producto");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"{conver}");
            Console.WriteLine($"El valor de producto es: {a}");
            Console.Write("Ingresa el precio del primer producto \n");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            prod1 = double.Parse(linea);
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el segundo producto");
            b = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"{conver}");
            Console.WriteLine($"El valor de producto es: {b}");
            Console.Write("Ingresa el precio del segundo producto \n");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            prod2 = double.Parse(linea);
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el tercer producto");
            c = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"{conver}");
            Console.WriteLine($"El valor de producto es: {c}");
            Console.Write("Ingresa el precio del tercer producto \n");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            prod3 = double.Parse(linea);
            int impuesto, descuento;
            if (impuesto <= 4000) 
            {
                descuento = impuesto * 20;
            }
            else
            if(impuesto <=10000)
            {
                descuento = impuesto * 50;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            /*ivaprod1 = prod1 + (prod1 * .20);
            ivaprod2 = prod2 + (prod2 * .20);
            ivaprod3 = prod3 + (prod3 * .20);*/
            total = prod1 + prod2 + prod3;
            Console.Write("el precio del primer producto es: $ " + prod1 + "  y con iva es: $" + impuesto + "\n\n");
            Console.Write("el precio del segundo producto es: $ " + prod2 + "  y con iva es: $" + impuesto + "\n\n");
            Console.Write("el precio del tercer producto es: $ " + prod3 + "  y con iva es: $" + impuesto + "\n\n");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Les agradezco por su ayuda

**

Comment: Por qué lleva etiquetas de bases de datos y sql?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y el problema cual es?

Comment: También debes revisar tu explicación, creo que estás confundiendo dos términos: el _impuesto _ es un mondo adicional que el cliente debe pagar, el _descuento_ es un monto que se resta al monto a pagar. En la explicación usas ambos términos como sinónimos. Ahora, si por "descuento" te refieres a la retención de impuestos (en VEN, ECU, etc...) el descuento debe restarse en vez de sumarse.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si colocas un ejemplo completo de los montos, que indique: Monto del producto (precio), impuesto a pagar, descuento a restar, monto total (precio + impuesto - descuento). En tu ejemplo no estoy seguro de si los "3000" son el precio del artículo, o el monto de impuesto antes del descuento.